# How to develop a Decision Support System

Tags: decision-tree

I would like to develop a decision support system for diagnosis disease. I am newbie for the programming. Can anyone suggest which programming language is most suitable?

Answer (score 0):

That really depends on what you want to do exactly (do you want to use prebuilt libraries?).

I see you added weka as a tag. Java is a good option, since it's so versatile, powerful, fast and fairly easy to use, implementable as a web service, plus you can use the weka library for quickly building trees.

But really, any other programming language (C++, python, matlab) will have the power to build a tree.

Answer (score -1):

You have to design a  decision mathematical model. In order to do that, you need a back ground in statistic, data mining or even fuzzy logic.

And then, you code the decision making algorithm to get the final results. I suggest you should have a validation phase to ensure your program is useful and correct.